# Mean stack application to save data from sensor and display alerts

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The data is generated by an url and I need to catch that data and save in the database I have designed my schema but I don't know how to catch that data and save in the database like req.****(what command need to use to catch data, defined in my controller)
Example for data genetated console result: OPTIONS /api/users 200 2.518 ms - 4

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! So, as I understand, your problem is, basically, starting with a POST request to your application server, right? You're on Mongo/Node.js. How are you planning to save/retrieve the information to the database (mongoose, mongo driver, etc)? Can you provide some code you've been working with so far?

Comment: Hello @Orlando thank you for your response I am working with MEAN stack and I resolved it, the issue I faced is I didn't install cors on my controller where headers are blocked from unknown sources once I set headers by cors my code is working.